# How do i get the solution name when running from a extension?

Tags: visual-studio, mef

I'm coding an extension in C# using the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF).
How can I get the current open solution name or the project names?

The class i'm been digging deep in is the IWpfTextView but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a Package class in your assembly, you can do:

DTE2 = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2;
 string fullName = dte.Solution.FullName;

Otherwise you can get the DTE via:
 DTE dte = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE") as DTE;
 string fullName = dte.Solution.FullName;

and I see people talk about a more 'MEF' oriented way of the getting the DTE but I've not tried it..

Once you have the DTE object you can then traverse the projects with the solution.

ref: [VSIX: Getting DTE object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792333/vsix-getting-dte-object/3794748#3794748)
ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solution.aspx