# "This function requires all threads to evaluate" after `new AdhocWorkspace()` within VS custom visualizer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, debuggervisualizer

I am trying to write a visualizer that [maps expressions in an expression tree to Roslyn syntax nodes](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToSyntaxNode), in order to generate code for the expression tree. Part of the syntax tree generation is a call to the `AdhocWorkspace` constructor.

When I run the visualizer using the `VisualizerDevelopmentHost`, everything works just fine:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace _testVisualizer {
    class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Expression<Func<bool>> expr = () => true;
            var data = new TestVisualizerData(expr);
            var visualizerHost = new VisualizerDevelopmentHost(data, typeof(TestVisualizer));
            visualizerHost.ShowVisualizer();

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to use the visualizer through the Visual Studio UI (by hovering over `expr`, clicking on the magnifying glass icon and choosing my visualizer), I get the following message:

> Unable to perform function evaluation on the process being debugged.
>
> **Additional information**
>
> The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

I've identified the following as triggering the error:

```
workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
```

which assigns to the `workspace` field on my `Mapper` class ([source](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToSyntaxNode/blob/master/ExpressionTreeTransform/Mapper.cs#L29)).

**Why does calling the `AdhocWorkspace` constructor trigger this warning? How can I work around this?**

---

This is an MCVE that demonstrates the issue:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(_testVisualizer.TestVisualizer), typeof(_testVisualizer.TestVisualizerDataObjectSource), Target = typeof(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression), Description = "Test Visualizer")]

namespace _testVisualizer {
    public class TestVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider) {
            var data = (TestVisualizerData)objectProvider.GetObject();
            var txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Status");
            var window = new Window {
                DataContext = data,
                Content = txt
            };
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class TestVisualizerData {
        public TestVisualizerData() { }
        public TestVisualizerData(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) {
            var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
            Status = "Success";
        }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestVisualizerDataObjectSource : VisualizerObjectSource {
        public override void GetData(object target, Stream outgoingData) {
            var expr = (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)target;
            var data = new TestVisualizerData(expr);
            base.GetData(data, outgoingData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A duplicate [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625059/how-to-debug-code-compiled-with-roslyn-in-a-visual-studio-extension-inside-curre).  I concur with the author's answer, this exception is intentional to prevent deadlock.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you clarify how this is a duplicate of the linked question? Are you saying that if the current solution would use a compiled version of the visualizer (instead of a project reference), then it would work?

Comment: @HansPassant I was unable to test this. Having created a new solution with only a reference to the visualizer DLL, the visualizer isn't registered with Visual Studio.

Comment: @HansPassant Looking over at this over two years later, I still fail to see the relevance here. The instance of the Roslyn compiler I am trying to open is self-contained within the visualizer, and thus unrelated to any Roslyn instance used by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the `AdhocWorkspace` [alternate constructor](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/AdhocWorkspace.cs,18) could be leveraged to use the SyntaxNode API in a single thread.

I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/32568).